# html doc search with multiple params in order

Tags: ruby, parsing

I'm trying to parse a html raw file using nokogiri.

```
html_file = URI.open(url).read
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_file)
puts html_doc.search("p", "h2").map(&:text)
```

When I do this, I get all the "p" text and then all the "h2" text. Is there a way to get them in the order that they appear in the original text?

I tried something like this below but it doesn't quite work

```
puts html_doc.search("p" || "h2").map(&:text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, found my own answer.

> puts html_doc.search("p, h2").map(&:text)

Comment: Don't be sorry, adding your own answer is a great way to help other users who might have the same question as you. Make sure to accept the answer so people know this is the correct way of solving the problem. 